# Button is not showing the near by places in Android Studio

Tags: google-maps, android-studio

I am New in Android studio.I am working on Google Maps. I have set Android Api and Browser Api in my project and also import the Google play library. Everything looks fine But after executing the program when I click Find button then it Does not doing anything.

i am following the google map tutorial from this link

http://javapapers.com/android/android-show-current-location-on-map-using-google-maps-api/

Am i missing something? 
Thank in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

you need to import Google places API for showing the near by places on map .

https://developers.google.com/places/

go to this link and set your dependencies

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3330854?hl=en

this can also be useful

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'                                          am i missing something ?

Comment: i have already set the API keys, but button is doing nothing . :/